# Should Windows Multipoint Server stations on individual video cards support hardware video acceleration?

Tags: graphics, opengl, multiseat, windows-multipoint-server

I've set up a test machine with multiple PCI-e nVidia GF440 Video cards and installed Windows Multipoint Server 2011.

I use the same kind of hardware set up with a BeTwin multiseat solution to create a class lab for Google SketchUp teaching (highly OpenGL dependent) and it works ok.

On the Multipoint Windows test machine the drivers seem to be installed OK but I don´t seem to get any hardware video acceleration. Is this a intrinsic limitation of this solution or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand 3D acceleration is not supported with Multipoint Server. There has been a [similar question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/257050) and an observation similar to yours [documented at the MS support forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmultipointserver/thread/989ec280-4d82-48b7-8246-3537f95c02d7).